# How to create a summary using dictionaries based on an excel with empty cells using python? (vlookup with python)

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have an Excel spreadsheet. In column A I have an ID, column B I have the description.

The same ID and same text repeats `x` times, but the final row of that ID has no description. And then the ID changes.

Here is a screenshot of the file:

[image: excel file]

I want with Python to read downwards. When it finds a new ID, append it to a dictionary with its description, and then go to the next ID with its description.

It´s like the `vlookup` formula, but with Python.

Comment: hi, are you willing to use pandas ? it makes it very easy. all in all two lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you're trying to achieve:

```
import csv
datafile = open('asdf.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile,delimiter=',')
data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)    

output = []
ids = []
for d in data:
    if d[0] not in ids:
        ids.append(d[0])
        output.append(d)

print(output)
```

From this:

[image]

You get this:

```
[['\xef\xbb\xbf1', 'ab'], ['1', 'b'], ['2', 'ab'], ['3', 'z'], ['33', 'ab']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data into pandas dataframe using `read_excel`, and then use `fillna` with `method='ffill'` on description column, after which you save the table. A three-liner, basically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you like using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

in case you don't know how to read excel files with pd it's done with [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd
# header = None in case you don't have any header rows in your excel
# names are the columns names
df = pd.read_excel(file_dir,sheetName,header=None,names=['A','B','C'])
```

for this case i used this data set:

```
     A      B      C
0  ID1  Desc1  stuff
1  ID1  Desc1  stuff
2  ID1  Desc1  stuff
3  ID1    NaN    NaN    # NaN are empty cells ( missing values )
4  ID2  Desc2  stuff
5  ID2  Desc2  stuff
6  ID2    NaN    NaN
```

so once you have your dataframe, all you need to create your dicts are [pandas.drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['A'],keep='first',inplace=True)
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(df['A'],df['B'])}
```

that will give you `d`:

```
{'ID1': 'Desc1', 'ID2': 'Desc2'}
```

Hope that was helpful.